# Errors on ContactPoint Schema

Tags: schema

I am getting this error on all contact point code and I can't seem to find how to design it. On Schema.org examples it looks like this is correct. I want to be sure I can get a structured snippet if possible.

Error: ContactPoint must be attached to a parent with a declared type.

Code:

Accident/Theft: 01-800-555-5555
Roadside Assistance: 01-800-555-5556

Answer (score 0):

Instances of ContactPoint may appear as a property value for properties types such as Organization, Message, ServiceChannel, Person, and more. See also http://schema.org/ContactPoint.

The code snippet below gives an example. It is tested on https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

```
 <div>
      <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemscope>
        <div itemprop="contactPoint" itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPoint" itemscope>
          <meta itemprop="contactType" content="customer service" />
          <meta itemprop="telephone" content="+1-400-500-6000" />
        </div>
        <h1 itemprop="name">My Company</h1>
        <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.mycompany.com/" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, coded in json-ld:

```
{ "@context" : "http://schema.org",
      "@type" : "Organization",
      "url" : "http://mycompany.com",
      "name" : "My Company",
      "contactPoint" : [
        {
          "@type" : "ContactPoint",
          "telephone" : "+1-400-500-6000",
          "contactType" : "customer service"
        }] 
}
```

Comment: I do exactly like this but the schema validator returns a "The property contactType is not recognized by the schema (e.g. schema.org) for an object of type Organization."